# How to get the client's real IP in golang in net/rpc

Tags: go, rpc

I have a requirement that requires the rpc server to get the client’s **real IP** and current connection `net.Conn`.

I used to get it through the following example method

```golang
// example_server.go
type MathService struct{}
type Args struct {
    A, B int
}
type Reply struct {
    Result int
}
func (m *MathService) Multiply(args *Args, reply *Reply) error {
    reply.Result = args.A * args.B
    return nil
}
func main() {
    // Create an instance of the MathService
    mathService := new(MathService)
    // Register MathService for RPC
    rpc.Register(mathService)
    // Create a TCP listener
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:1234")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error starting server:", err)
        return
    }
    defer listener.Close()
    fmt.Println("Server listening on :1234")
    for {
        // Accept incoming connections
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting connection:", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("remote ip addr: %s\n", conn.RemoteAddr().String())
        // Serve the connection in a new goroutine
        go rpc.ServeConn(conn)
    }
}

// example_client.go
type Args struct {
    A, B int
}
type Reply struct {
    Result int
}
func main() {
    // Connect to the server
    client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:1234")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to server:", err)
        return
    }
    defer client.Close()
    // Prepare the arguments for the RPC call
    args := &Args{A: 5, B: 3}
    // Call the Multiply method remotely
    var reply Reply
    err = client.Call("MathService.Multiply", args, &reply)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error calling Multiply:", err)
        return
    }
    // Print the result
    fmt.Printf("Result: %d\n", reply.Result)
}
```

But what the `RemoteAddr` method gets is not necessarily the **real IP** of the client. For example, forwarded through **NAT**.

Therefore, I hope to manually call the`ReportRealIP` function to report the **real IP**, but I cannot get the **current** connected `net.Conn` in the **rpc function**.

But I searched some information and found no way to achieve my needs. Is there a way to get the two variables I want? Looking forward to your reply

> The reason for needing **real IP** and `net.Conn` is roughly for **two-way communication**. I hope to be able to send RPC requests to the client of a specific IP to perform certain operations. For example, issue RPC commands to certain Agent services to execute a certain script.

**Additional information**
Pseudo code for my expected result

```golang
// client.go
rpc.Call("Server.ReportRealIP","1,2,3,4", resp)



// server.go
var globalMap map[string]net.Conn
func (m *Server) ReportRealIP(args *string, reply *Reply) error {
    clientRealIP := args
    // get current call net.Conn
    
    globalMap[clientRealIP] = current net.Conn
    return nil
}

// other.go

//Read the Conn of some specific IPs from globalMap and send an RPC request to the client after encapsulation
```

Comment: "is not necessarily the real IP of the client" -- can you elaborate? What are for example values you get that which you consider wrong? What would you expect instead? Also, any network node can have multiple IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and it usually has!

Comment: For example, forwarded through NAT. When there are multiple IPv4s, choose the ones I specify to report, such as client startup parameters.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that your problem is NAT! This changes everything.

Answer (score 0):

> I mentioned above that the IP obtained through `RemoteAdd`r may be the address forwarded by **NAT**, not the real client localip.
> Therefore, I hope to report the client localIP through the **ReportRealIP RPC function**, but in this case, the current connection information cannot be obtained in the **ReportRealIP** function.
> The summary is that I hope the client calls `Call("server.ReportRealIP","clientReal IP",resp)`, and then the server gets the clientRealIP and saves it in a map. **The map is `<clientRealIP>: <current net. Conn>`**

So you need a way to map the real IP reported by the client to the current `net.Conn` object in the `ReportRealIP` function. But the `net.Conn` object is not directly accessible in the RPC call context.

However, when a client connects to the server, you have access to the `net.Conn` object (through [`net.Listen()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Listen) + [`listener.Accept()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPListener.Accept)): by maintaining a mapping of the initial remote address (even if it is a NAT address) to the `net.Conn` object and then updating it when the client reports its real IP, you should get what you need.

```bash
 +-------------+    TCP/IP    +----------------+
 |             | <----------> |                |
 |  Client(s)  |              |  RPC Server    |
 |             |              |                |
 +-------------+              +----------------+
     |   ^                           |
     |   |                           |
     v   |                   Accept Connection
 Report  |                   Store Connection
 Real IP |                   Map Temp IP to Conn
     |   |                   Update Map with Real IP
     |   |                           |
     |   v                           v
 +-------------+    TCP/IP    +----------------+
 |             | <----------> |                |
 |  Client(s)  |              |  RPC Server    |
 |             |              |                |
 +-------------+              +----------------+
```

The server code would store the connection against the initial remote address (NAT address). And update this mapping when the real IP is reported:

```golang
// server.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
    "sync"
)

var (
    initialConnMap = make(map[string]net.Conn)
    realIPConnMap  = make(map[string]net.Conn)
    mutex          = &sync.Mutex{}
)

type Server struct{}

type Args struct {
    RealIP string
}

func (s *Server) ReportRealIP(args *Args, reply *struct{}) error {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()

    // Find the connection that matches the reported real IP
    for natIP, conn := range initialConnMap {
        if conn.RemoteAddr().String() == args.RealIP {
            realIPConnMap[args.RealIP] = conn
            delete(initialConnMap, natIP) // Clean up the initial map
            fmt.Printf("Mapped real IP %s to connection\n", args.RealIP)
            break
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    rpc.Register(new(Server))

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:1234")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error starting server:", err)
        return
    }
    defer listener.Close()
    fmt.Println("Server listening on :1234")

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting connection:", err)
            continue
        }

        initialRemoteAddr := conn.RemoteAddr().String()
        mutex.Lock()
        initialConnMap[initialRemoteAddr] = conn
        mutex.Unlock()

        fmt.Printf("Connection accepted from: %s\n", initialRemoteAddr)

        go rpc.ServeConn(conn)
    }
}
```

The client will report its real IP through the `ReportRealIP` RPC function.

```golang
// client.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/rpc"
)

func main() {
    client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:1234")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to server:", err)
        return
    }
    defer client.Close()

    realIP := "Your_Client_Real_IP" // Replace with the actual real IP
    args := &struct{ RealIP string }{RealIP: realIP}
    var reply struct{}

    err = client.Call("Server.ReportRealIP", args, &reply)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error calling ReportRealIP:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Reported real IP to server")
}
```

But that supposes the client is accurately and truthfully reporting its real IP. You should implement validation and security measures to make sure this mechanism is not misused.

And If clients are behind a NAT, they may not know their public IP without external help (like an external IP lookup service).

---

The core limitation of the proposed solution is that it assumes a unique mapping between the IP address seen by the server (NAT IP) and the client's connection. That assumption could break down in a NAT scenario where multiple clients can appear to have the same IP address (the NAT's address).

You might consider using a unique client identifier (instead of relying on IP addresses for initial mapping): that could be a client-generated ID or a combination of factors (like IP and port) that uniquely identifies each client behind NAT.
Map this unique identifier to the `net.Conn` object on initial connection. When the client reports its real IP, update the map to associate this real IP with the unique identifier. Make sure the logic accounts for cases where multiple clients behind the same NAT report different real IPs.

---

> *But* I found that this cannot take into account all situations, because I found that sometimes the **real IP and the remote IP are far **different**.
>
> For example, the server's internal network IP is `10.xx.xx.xx`, but the remote IP is `152.xx.xx.xxx:12345`. Although the port can be split, `net.Coo` cannot be mapped through the above method.

So there is a discrepancy between internal (private) network IPs and external (public) IPs. In such cases, the IP address the server sees (the external IP) can be significantly different from the client's actual internal IP. That difference renders the initial IP-to-connection mapping (based on the external IP) ineffective for identifying the correct `net.Conn` object when the client reports its internal IP. While the port number can help distinguish different connections coming from the same external IP, it does not solve the issue of mapping the reported internal IP to the correct `net.Conn` object.

You could try and use a unique session identifier: Instead of relying on IP addresses for mapping, use a unique session identifier generated by the client or the server at the beginning of each connection. That identifier should be included in every RPC call, allowing the server to correctly map the session to the `net.Conn` object. The client sends this identifier in the `ReportRealIP` RPC call, and the server uses it to update the mapping.

Or you could have the client establish a separate, short-lived connection to the server specifically for reporting its real IP. That ensures the `net.Conn` object used for reporting is directly associated with the client's real IP. The client opens a new connection, reports its real IP, and then closes the connection. The server uses this separate connection to update the mapping.

Or you could use a combination of the external IP and port as a key for the initial mapping. When the client reports its real IP, include the port number as well, allowing the server to find the correct `net.Conn` object. Store connections in the map using "externalIP:port" as the key. The client reports its real IP and the port it is connected to, allowing the server to find the matching `net.Conn`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, *but* I found that this cannot take into account all situations, because I found that sometimes the **real IP and the remote IP are far different**. For example, the server's internal network IP is `10.xx.xx.xx`, but the remote IP is `152.xx.xx.xxx:12345`. Although the port can be split, `net.Coo` cannot be mapped through the above method